# click on check box with protractor only if not checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to get a list of checkboxes by css and to click on checkbox only if not selected, I manage to get the list, but for some reason I can't validate if the element is selected.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        element.all(By.css('#dropdown li input')).then(function(rows) {
            expect(rows.length).toBe(number_of_widgets);
            for (var i = 0; i < number_of_widgets; i++) {
                rows[i].isSelected().then(function(selected) {
                    if (!selected) {
                        rows[i].click();
                    }
                    waits(100);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry! I missed the specific line of code. You are already doing a `isSelected()`. They way I had handled this kind of issue was to use the `for` loop outside of the checkbox parent. Then iterate over the checkboxes as child nodes and check using `isSelected()`.

Comment: no, it should return true/false from the promise

Comment: can you provide example please?

Comment: What I think is that probably `rows[i]` is not giving you the correct element. Do some thing like this instead-
`for (var i = 1; i < number_of_widgets+1; i++){
if(!(element(by.css('#dropdown li input:nth-child(i)')).isSelected())){
element(by.css('#dropdown li input:nth-child(i)')).click()
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try following by substituting the inner loop with:

```
..
rows.then(function(element){
    var eleUnchecked = !element.getAttribute('checked');
    if (eleUnchecked) {
        return element.click();
    }
}
..
```

Comment: This is not Protractor/WebdriverJS-compatible; obtaining values from the DOM must be done through callbacks/promises.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.all(By.css('#dropdown li input')).then(function(rows) {
    expect(rows.length).toBe(number_of_widgets);
    for (var i = 0; i < number_of_widgets; i++) {
        rows[i].isSelected().then(function(selected) {
            if (!selected) {
                rows[i].click();
            }
            if (selected) {
                rows.isSelected = false ;
            }
            waits(100);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're getting `wait` from but this all looks asynchronous to me. Try this, it will make `i` equal what you expect:

```
element.all(By.css('#dropdown li input')).then(function(rows) {
    expect(rows.length).toBe(number_of_widgets);
    for (var i = 0; i < number_of_widgets; i++) {
        rows[i].isSelected().then(function(i){return function(selected) {
            if (!selected) {
                rows[i].click();
            }
            waits(100);
        }}(i));
    }
});
```

Comment: You could also (instead) wrap the function in brackets and `.bind(i)` to it, then refer to `i` as `this` on the inside

Comment: I tried all answers and nothing is working for me. Does somebody know a way to get list of checkboxes and to check one that is not checked?

Comment: Try the information found on this page; you simply use the property `checked` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the promise to your variable inside the loop

it('should add active class to selected rows', function () {
            var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('task in tasks'));

```
        todoList.then(function (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length ; i++) {
                var input = todoList.get(i).element(by.css('input'));
                var promise = input.isSelected();
                promise.then(function (sts) {
                    if (sts == false) {
                        this.click();
                    }
                }.bind(input));
            }

            element.all(by.css('.taskRow.active')).then(function (i) {
                expect(i.length).toBe(10);
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution.

```
element.all(by.css('#dropdown li input')).then(function(rows) {
    expect(rows.length).toBe(number_of_widgets);
    rows.each(function(row) {
        row.isSelected().then(function(selected) {
            if (!selected) {
                rows[i].click();
            }
            waits(100);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 1; i < number_of_widgets+1; i++) { 
    if (!(element(by.css('#dropdown li input:nth-child(i)')).isSelected())) { 
        element(by.css('#dropdown li input:nth-child(i)')).click()
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer to my question, I want to check it on my rows object before .click()

Comment: Downvote for using css properties where the DOM property `childNodes` would have been more appropriate, and for not correctly introducing the value of `i` to the interpreter. Even if this code worked I would never use it.